# How to enable ethernet port for android3.2 in Virtual box

Tags: android, virtualbox

I have get android3.2 image from
http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list
the filename is android-x86-3.2-RC2-asus_laptop.iso

It can not access the network, in terminal, I found there is no network, actually I have configure two network adapter in Virtual box.

I can not find the ethernet port. in "Terminal" or in "Setting"

BTW, I can access the network for image:android-x86-2.2-generic.iso.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this:

http://www.vmlite.com/vmlite/Android-v4.7z
(from: http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=158&func=view&catid=9&id=8838 ).

It's a premade virtual machine of ICS. I've just loaded into Virtual Box and the browser can load webpages without problems.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've tested in Mac Os and it doesnt work... Does it need some extra configuration in VB?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there is no ethernet module within the kernel. May be the next release :(

Comment: Thanks. A more question, how can I upload my app to this android. the 3.2 emulator seem very slow, so I would like use the android@VirtualBox to run my application.

Comment: You can see at : http://www.android-x86.org/documents/debug-howto. Indeed the emulator is very slow (sometimes 1mn to start ! on i7 !!) because of its ARM emulation to x86